# How to use Maxima if then else

Tags: if-statement, maxima

does anyone know how to use standard if then else structure in Maxima syntax when you need more than one instruction after then and else???   Like a block in a standard computer language???
Thanks
leon

Answer (score 5):

You can put multiple expressions into `block(...)` or `(...)`. The difference is that `block` allows local variables, e.g. `block([a, b], a: ..., b: ...)`.

For both `block(...)` and `(...)`, the result value is whatever was evaluated last. When there aren't any control structures such as `if`, the last expression in the `block(...)` or `(...)` is evaluated last. Otherwise, the result of the `block(...)` or `(...)` is whatever is the result of control structure. See also `return`.

Example:

```
if x < 4
    then block([y], print("Hi, x is less than 4"), y: 2*x, y - 1)
    else (print("I guess x >= 4"), x^3 - 10);
```